# Integrate multiple Dialogflow agents to single google assistant action

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I've gone through the actions console. Once in the respective project (created with agent), it allows to add a project but then selecting a project (which is another dialogflow agent) creates a new google actions project with its own development and deploy settings. Isn't there a way that I can deploy multiple agents (projects) on a **single** google assistant channel.

The reason is that I'd be asking users to select which bot they would like to have a conversation with. Imagine this as various agents dealing with totally different products for a company. So I have one bot for an insurance products and another for personal loan products. If I have more than 5 product lines like that, the conversation in dialogflow could become bloated with intents, entities and contexts. That's why I want to have different dialogflow agents at the backend to have a different conversational experience for each product's consumers.

On the website, they can be transferred to respective agent but how can I achieve this in Google Assistant?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, For each Google action, there is a dialogflow agent created and for each dialogflow agent, a google cloud project is created. You can only have one dialogflow agent per project. 
Now,
To implement what you want, you would have to custom build the feature where you can ask your user which bot they would want to talk to. One of the ways to achieve this would be a bot-to-bot transfer in which you create a single bot in which you ask which bot the user would like to chat with, then in fulfillment implement a bot-to-bot transfer.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a way to do bot-to-bot transfer in fulfillment?

Comment: There isnt a built in way to do that. What you might have to do is:
When an intent goes to fulfillment and you need to transfer to another bot, send a detectIntent request to another bot with the incoming phrase. You would need to maintain a session such that all the interactions after that transfer one ould redirect to the intended bot.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I need to explore bot-to-bot transfer. I was hoping to have a solution provided by GCP itself.

Comment: Surely there will be some tweaking required in intent and specifically contexts to be transferred adequately. Right now, with given GCP configuration options, I think its a workable approach to have a mediator bot.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call that a "transfer". That is more of a front-end proxy.